# Concatenate variables in a regular expression string with preg_match()

Tags: php, regex

I'm using `preg_match()` function which determines whether a function is executed.

```
if( preg_match( '/^([0-9]+,){0,3}[0-9]+$/', $string ) ) { ... }
```

However I have to use a integer variable and integrate it in the regular expression:

```
$integer = 4;
if( preg_match( '/^([0-9]+,){0,' . $integer . '}[0-9]+$/', $string ) ) { ... }
```

but it doesn't match when it should. How is it that I can't concatenate a variable in the regex string?

**Edit:**

`strval($integer)` has solved my problem. I had to convert the integer value into a string before concatenating it (although I don't understand why):

```
$integer = 4;
if( preg_match( '/^([0-9]+,){0,' . strval($integer) . '}[0-9]+$/', $string ) ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever concatenating a variable into a regex pattern, you should do so by passing the variable to [the `preg_quote` function](http://www.php.net/preg_quote).

However, if the variable var is, like it is in your example `4`, that won't make any difference. The pattern you're using will be:

```
/^([0-9]+,){0,4}[0-9]+$/
```

In which case, if it doesn't work: check the `$string` value, and make *sure* the pattern matches. BTW, `/^(\d+,){,4}\d+$/` is shorter and does the same thing.

Calling `strval` doesn't solve anything, AFAIK... I've tested the code without `strval`, using the following snippet:

```
$string = '1234,32';
if (preg_match( '/^([0-9]+,){0,4}[0-9]+$/', $string) )
{
    echo 'matches',PHP_EOL;
    $count = 4;
    if (preg_match( '/^([0-9]+,){0,'.$count.'}[0-9]+$/', $string ) )
        echo 'matches, too',PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output was, as I expected:

```
matches
matches, too
```

In your case, I'd simply write:

```
$count = 4;
preg_match('/^(\d+,){,'.preg_quote($count, '/').'}\d+$/', $string);
```

This is *undeniably* safer than just calling `strval`, because you're not accounting for possible special regex chars (`+[]{}/\$^?!:<=*.` and the like)

Comment: I found the issue. I have posted an answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: @ManoloSalsas: I don't think you did. Added reasons why I don't believe `strval` is the answer to my answer, and why `strval`, even if it _does_ solve the problem shouldn't be trusted